# PHP Submiited Form Error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have an error while creating my requests form.

```
<?php

require 'database.php';
$message = '';

if(!empty($_POST['username'])):

    // Enter the new user in the database
    $sql = "INSERT INTO survey (username, birthdate, bio, website, reason) VALUES (:username, :birthdate, :bio, :website, :reason)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':birthdate', $_POST['birthdate']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':bio', $_POST['bio']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':website', $_POST['website']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':reason', $_POST['reason']);

    if( $stmt->execute() ):
        $message = 'Successfully submitted your verification request, make sure that the email address provided in your account is accessable that we will answer through your provided email address!';
    else:
        $message = 'Sorry, there must have been an issue submitting your verification request. Please try again!';
    endif;

endif;

?>
```

This is my form, it says "Sorry, there must have been an issue submitting your verification request"

And my HTML form is :

```
<form action="home.php" method="POST">

        <input type="text" placeholder="@username" name="username" required>
        <input type="text" placeholder="e.g: January 1, 2001" name="birthdate" required>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Some text about you" name="bio" required>
        <input type="text" placeholder="What website are you working in? (optional)" name="website">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Why do you think you have to be verified?" name="reason" required>
        <input type="submit" value="Finish">

        </form>
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: PDO `errorInfo` function will tell you more.

Comment: Your code looks fine, I'm guessing database.php has worked with other queries? Also what data type is your birthdate column?